# When to use type alias vs. single-value union type in Elm

Tags: elm, type-alias, union-types

I've been reading over [Richard Feldman's Elm SPA app example](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example), and I'm seeing a number of [examples](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example/blob/master/src/Data/User.elm#L58) of things like this:

```
type Username
    = Username String
```

and I'm not sure when it makes sense to use something like that, a single-value union type, vs. just a type alias like this:

```
type alias Username
    = String
```

When is it appropriate to use a single-value union type vs. just using a type alias?

Comment: The example you have shown is referred to as an opaque type. Using one allows you to hide the implementation details from other parts of your program (or in the case of libraries, from the consumer). You can read more about them in the [Elm package help](http://package.elm-lang.org/help/design-guidelines#keep-tags-and-record-constructors-secret) (see the section entitled "Keep tags and record constructors secret").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule for when it is appropriate, but I tend to follow a few rules of thumb. Let's use an authenticate function example that takes a username and password, both of which are string values.

At a bare minimum, without any additional alias or types, the annotation could be this:

```elm
authenticate : String -> String -> Bool
```

Given that annotation, it isn't clear which parameter is the username and which is the password. We can improve the readability by using type aliases:

```elm
type alias Username = String
type alias Password = String

authenticate : Username -> Password -> Bool
```

This is better for consumers of my package but type aliases won't disallow you from accidentally swapping the parameters in calling code. For example, this problematic function would compile:

```elm
login : Username -> Password -> Bool
login username password =
    if authenticate password username then ...
```

If you want to go a step further and force the explicit declaration of the type every time you use it, you could avoid that type of error because the compiler will catch mixups:

```elm
type Username = Username String
type Password = Password String
```

With that definition, you must now explicitly unwrap and package the strings in either a Username or Password constructor every time you use it. This is especially useful for things like units of measure, where such a concept could have [avoided the loss of a Mars mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter)

As you see in Richard's example, going the route of a full type and type constructor means you'll need separate boilerplate functions for json decoding, encoding, etc, which can get tedious. You'll need to find the right balance for your team and projects.